# Setting log levels in RdotNet

Tags: r, r.net

I am trying to use the R {forecast} package on Windows using RDotNet.

Question: Is there a way to control the level of logging output across RDotNet/R?
For example, executing the RdotNet code

`var accuracy = rengine.Evaluate("accuracy(fcst)").AsNumeric();`

causes the result of evaluation to get logged to console (or log file) as well.
Is there a way to control this either in RDotNet or R or {forecast} ?

(I had tried this sometime ago using R 3.1.1 and RdotNet 1.5.15.  Recently I upgraded to the latest - R 3.2.2 and RdotNet 1.6.5.  I don't recall seeing this in the previous versions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REngine` object has a property `AutoPrint`, set to true by default (mirroring the default behavior of R). Setting it to false will not print things out unless explicitly requested via the `print` function (I think, as I recall).

You can look at [this sample code](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet-onboarding/tree/master/SourceRCode) to see it used. Also, a [recent discussion](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/645926) touched on this.

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I was looking for.